# https traffic to specific ip addresses using elb

Tags: amazon-elb

I have created a failover environment with route 53 and two elbs. Every elb have to attach multiple app servers. If allow https traffic to open everyone the application accessible but when i restrict the https traffic to specific ip address range the application is not accessible even those ip addresses who have permission.

Answer (score 0):

I assume when you say you allow http traffic from specific IP addresses ,you are doing it at the security group level.If yes then make sure you modify the security groups of the Load balancers and not the backend instances.The backend instances will receive http traffic from the load balancer IPs (which would be your ELB subnets cidr block or if not being too restrictive you can allow http traffic from the vpc cidr range.
Additionally ensure that the load balancers and the backend instances have different security groups.

ELB SG > HTTP:80 ,SOURCE 
BACKEND SG -> HTTP:80 ,SOURCE ELB SUBNET/VPC CIDR BLOCK

The would be simple changes if you are using ssl termination but the logic remains the same.

If you are not using security groups but something else then we would have to check your specific configuration.

Comment: Sumit Yes I am doing it at the security group level.
I have different security groups for ELB and backend instances.  The issue is resolved If restrict the https traffic at ELB level security group and also open the https traffic on instances level security groups. 
Have any way If restricting the traffic on instance level security groups because If I restrict the traffic on instances level security groups the Routes 53 health checks failed.